# can I refresh after edit of text

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am displaying results and I added the ability to edit the displayed result. That works I get pop up with the text I want to edit. However I need to go up and down to display the edited text. I have tried to add IsRefreshong property but that has the same result. Do you have any suggestions? I need to display the edited text after I click on "ok " in my pop up not have to scroll down or up and then see the updated property

here is my xaml

```
<ListView BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}" x:Name="list"
                        HasUnevenRows="True" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Results, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                        SelectionMode="None">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid  BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                                             <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                 
                                       <Label Grid.Column="1" Padding="0,3,3,0" Text ="{Binding FieldDescriptor}" Style="{StaticResource SubLabelBlackStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"  />
                                       <Label Grid.Column="3" Padding="0,3,3,0" Text="{Binding FieldValue}" Style="{StaticResource SubLabelBlackStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"  >
                                           <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                               <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.EditTextCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=list}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                           </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                       </Label>
                          
                                  </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

here is the back of my page

```
  public DisplayResult(RemoteCallResult<IEnumerable<DocumentData>> data)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ResultPageViewModel(data);
        }
```

ViewModel property isRefreshing

```
 public bool IsRefreshing
        {
            get => _isRefreshing;
            private set
            {
                _isRefreshing = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsRefreshing");
            }

        }
```

here is the edit method

```
public async Task EditTextAsync(DocumentData param)
        {
            PromptResult pResult = await UserDialogs.Instance.PromptAsync(new PromptConfig
            {
                InputType = InputType.Default,
                Text = param.FieldValue,
                Title = param.FieldValue,
            });
            if(pResult != null)
            {
               _isRefreshing = true;
                param.FieldValue = pResult.Text;
                Thread.Sleep(5);
              _isRefreshing = false;

            }
        }
```

MYmodel

```
public string FieldValue { get; set; }

public string FieldDescriptor { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Text="{Binding FieldValue,**Mode=TwoWay**}"

Add a two-way binding mode and you have not posted the *DocumentData* Model, Raise this FieldValue property in the model as well. It should do it.

Comment: , mode two doesn't help, I added my model. you mean add notify property c hanged to model?

Comment: @Rntakokoi yes the model property should also be raised like properties in ViewModel , You can have a look at fodyweaver to do all this for you easily 

one such link http://www.shenchauhan.com/blog/2018/6/18/fody-inotifypropertychanged-the-easy-way

you can find many online

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use is `IsRefreshing` tag for changing the value in the MVVM.

Here is running gif.

[image]

Please change the viewModel like following format. Achieve the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for all of your properties.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;

namespace PanCakeView
{
    public class MyModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       
        string fieldValue;
        public string FieldValue
        {
            set
            {
                if (fieldValue != value)
                {
                    fieldValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FieldValue");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return fieldValue;
            }
        }

      
        string fieldDescriptor;
        public string FieldDescriptor
        {
            set
            {
                if (fieldDescriptor != value)
                {
                    fieldDescriptor = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FieldDescriptor");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return fieldDescriptor;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my viewModel. I used `ObservableCollection` for testing.

```
   public class ResultPageViewModel
    {
       

        public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Results { get; set; }
        public ICommand EditTextCommand { protected set; get; }

        public ResultPageViewModel(ObservableCollection<MyModel> myModels)
        {
            Results = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
            foreach (var item in myModels)
            {
                Results.Add(item);
            }

            EditTextCommand = new Command<MyModel>(async (key) =>
            {
                PromptResult pResult = await UserDialogs.Instance.PromptAsync(new PromptConfig
                {
                    InputType = InputType.Default,
                    Text = key.FieldValue,
                    Title = "change value",
                });
                if (pResult!=null)
                {
                    key.FieldValue = pResult.Text;
                }
                
            });

        }
    }
```

I do not know which style you used. I just use style that I setted.

```
    <ListView BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" x:Name="list"
                        HasUnevenRows="True" 
                       
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Results, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                        SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid  BackgroundColor="Gray">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Padding="0,3,3,0" Text ="{Binding FieldDescriptor}"  HorizontalOptions="Start"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"  />
                            <Label Grid.Column="3" Padding="0,3,3,0" Text="{Binding FieldValue}"  HorizontalOptions="Start"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"  >
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.EditTextCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=list}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Label>

                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Here is layout's background code.

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<MyModel> data = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
            data.Add(new MyModel() { FieldDescriptor= "this is a Descriptor", FieldValue="1" });
            data.Add(new MyModel() { FieldDescriptor = "this is a Descriptor", FieldValue = "2" });
            data.Add(new MyModel() { FieldDescriptor = "this is a Descriptor", FieldValue = "3" });
            data.Add(new MyModel() { FieldDescriptor = "this is a Descriptor", FieldValue = "4" });
            data.Add(new MyModel() { FieldDescriptor = "this is a Descriptor", FieldValue = "5" });
            data.Add(new MyModel() { FieldDescriptor = "this is a Descriptor", FieldValue = "6" });
            this.BindingContext = new ResultPageViewModel(data);
        }
    }
```

==============**Update**=====================

If you use PopUp page，Here is running gif.

[image]

Here is my popup page code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages:PopupPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             x:Class="PanCakeView.MyPopUpPage">

    <Frame 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
            <StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="entryCardName"
                    FontSize="Small"
                    Placeholder="{Binding FieldValue}"
                    Text="{Binding FieldValue}"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    ReturnType="Next">
            </Entry>
             <Button Text="Ok" Command="{Binding ConfirmPopUpCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>


            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
   
</pages:PopupPage>
```

PopUp page's background code.

```
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MyPopUpPage : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
    {
        //public string FieldValue { get; set; }

        private string _fieldValue;
        public Command ConfirmPopUpCommand { get; }

        public string FieldValue
        {
            set
            {
                _fieldValue = value;

              
            }
            get { return _fieldValue; }
        }


        public MyPopUpPage(MyModel myModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _fieldValue = myModel.FieldValue;
            ConfirmPopUpCommand = new Command(async (key) => {
                myModel.FieldValue = FieldValue;
           
                await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);

            });

            this.BindingContext = this;
        }

       

     
    }
}
```

Here is `ResultPageViewModel.cs` new code.

```
  public class ResultPageViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MyModel> data;
        private INavigation navigation;

        public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Results { get; set; }
        public ICommand EditTextCommand { protected set; get; }

        public ResultPageViewModel(ObservableCollection<MyModel> myModels, INavigation navigation)
        {
            this.navigation = navigation;
            Results = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
            foreach (var item in myModels)
            {
                Results.Add(item);
            }

            EditTextCommand = new Command<MyModel>(async (key) =>
            {
                //PromptResult pResult = await UserDialogs.Instance.PromptAsync(new PromptConfig
                //{
                //    InputType = InputType.Default,
                //    Text = key.FieldValue,
                //    Title = "change value",
                //});
                //if (pResult!=null)
                //{
                //    key.FieldValue = pResult.Text;
                //}
                await navigation.PushPopupAsync(new MyPopUpPage(key));

               

            });

        }

        
    }
}
```

You need add `Navigation` attribute in DisplayResult page. `this.BindingContext = new ResultPageViewModel(data, Navigation);`

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I have decided to use POP up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64307619/popup-rg-plugins-after-edit-no-update-for-property/64327751#64327751 here Is my question

Comment: @Rntakokoi I update my answer, please test it, I use popup page to write a demo code to you. You do not Refresh property that you can get the result. And do not forget to accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue