# Popup RG plugins after edit no update for property

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am displaying my properties in list. I used to use Acr.UserDialogs to display popup however I have decided to switch to RG for better UI.

Now when I clock on one field and edit it when I go back to the original page the value stay the same as it was before update. I have tried to add RefreshPull but that doesn't help

Back of my page

```
  public DisplayResult(RemoteCallResult<IEnumerable<DocumentData>> data)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = _resultPageViewModel = new ResultPageViewModel(data);
        }
```

my Xaml

```
<ListView BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}" x:Name="list"  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="{Binding Update}"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Results, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                        SelectionMode="None">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid  BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                                             <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                 
                                       <Label Grid.Column="1" Padding="0,3,3,0" Text ="{Binding FieldDescriptor}" Style="{StaticResource SubLabelBlackStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"  />
                                       <Label Grid.Column="3" Padding="0,3,3,0" Text="{Binding FieldValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource SubLabelBlackStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"  >
                                           <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                               <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.EditTextCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=list}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                           </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                       </Label>
                                  </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

VIEWMODEL

```
 public string FieldValue
        {
            get => _fieldValue;
            set => SetValue(ref _fieldValue, value);
        }
        public ResultPageViewModel()
        {

        }

        public ResultPageViewModel(RemoteCallResult<IEnumerable<DocumentData>> data)
        {
            EditTextCommand = new Command<DocumentData>(async (key) => await EditTextAsync(key));
            Update = new Command<string>(async (key) => await UpdateValue(key));
            LoadText(data);        }

  public async Task EditTextAsync(DocumentData param)
        {
            await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new EditPopUp(param));
        }

        public async Task UpdateValue(string value)
        {
            _fieldValue = value;
        }
```

ViewModel POPUP

```
 private readonly ResultPageViewModel _resultPageViewModel;
        private string _fieldValue;
        public Command ConfirmPopUpCommand { get; }

        public string FieldValue
        {
            set
            {
                _fieldValue = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(FieldValue));
            }
            get { return _fieldValue; }
        }


        public EditPopUpViewModel(DocumentData param)
        {
            _resultPageViewModel = new ResultPageViewModel();
            _fieldValue = param.FieldValue;
            ConfirmPopUpCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteConfirmPopUpCommand());
          
        }

        private async Task ExecuteConfirmPopUpCommand()
        {
    
            await _resultPageViewModel.UpdateValue(_fieldValue);
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);
        }
```

POP UP

```
  <Entry x:Name="entryCardName"
                    FontSize="Small"
                    Placeholder="{Binding FieldValue}"
                    Text="{Binding FieldValue}"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    ReturnType="Next">
                </Entry>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you show the pop up, I think you should also pass the ViewModel to the popupPage:

```
  public async Task EditTextAsync(DocumentData param)
        {
            await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new EditPopUp(param), this);
        }
```

Then in the POPUP, you does not need to create a new one:

```
public MainPage(DocumentData param, ResultPageViewModel model)
{
    _fieldValue = param.FieldValue;
    Command ConfirmPopUpCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteConfirmPopUpCommand(model));

}

private async Task ExecuteConfirmPopUpCommand(ResultPageViewModel model)
{

    await model.UpdateValue(_fieldValue);
    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);
}
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work I am sorry. Still doesn't update the value on the result page

Comment: Have a try with my updated code, pass the model through command.

Comment: @Jack Hua - MSFT still doesn't update the whole page. I can see the data in the method, but I have added the update method on button and execute that on the result page and the value is null

Comment: in here  public async Task UpdateValue(string value)
        {
            _fieldValue = value;
        }

Comment: Change  _fieldValue  to  FieldValue.

Comment: Ok, I can see the value on the in FieldValue but it still doesn't update as when I pull the list

Comment: When you pull the list? What you need to do is make sure the model you modifying is the same model in the list. It's hard for me to test without your full codes.

Comment: I can see the value updating on here on the result page, but it doesn't update in the xaml   public string FieldValue
        {
            get => _fieldValue;
            set => SetValue(ref _fieldValue, value);
        }

Comment: The value will definitely update while I'm not sure if you are updating the same model without debugging the code.

Comment: Hello, you were right I was doing a mistake and updating different value. I have fixed that now. However The value still doesn't change. I changed this from string to the model   and when selecting I am adding index. public DocumentData FieldValue
        {
            get { return _fieldValue; }
            set
            {
                if(_fieldValue != value)
                {
                    _fieldValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FieldValue");
                }
            }         
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223078/discussion-between-vanessa-kensington-and-jack-hua-msft).

Comment: @Jack Hua please can you help

Comment: @VanessaKensington I really want to help you but I'm not able to debug your code. As I said before, what you need to do is make sure the model you modifying is the same model in the list. When the popup show, you should pass a current model to it and change the value of that model.

Answer (score 0):

this is updating the **private internal field**, bypassing the setter and `NotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public async Task UpdateValue(string value)
{
    _fieldValue = value;
}
```

you want to update the **public property** that will fire the setter and `NotifyPropertyChanged`

```
public async Task UpdateValue(string value)
{
    FieldValue = value;
}
```

Comment: why does EditPopUpViewModel create its own instance of ResultPageViewModel?

Comment: so I can call the update method. Should I do it differently?

Comment: Your other page already has an instance of this VM.  Creating a new instance and calling Update doesn't do anything because the new instance isn't connected to your other page.

Comment: @Rntakokoi Use the same instance of ResultPageViewModel in both pages.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand how to use the same instance in two pages .. create static ?